# Checking if an item exists in a dictionary, is this a bad practice?

Tags: python, dictionary, exception

This code is in python and works just fine:

```
# tests if class exists in the dictionary attrs
try:
    self.attrs['class']
# if it doesnt python will throw an exception
except KeyError:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass"
# else it is defined, so we concat someclass to previous value
else:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % self.attrs['class']
```

Although, I am afraid this is not a good practice, because if python have an update and changes the name of exception thrown, it may stop working. Is it a bad practice? Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: From my understanding of pythonism it's actually not. You shouldn't worry about the name changing. That would break too much code to be put into anything other than a major update, which you would know about.

Comment: You might find http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175655/python-forgiveness-vs-permission-and-duck-typing interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot more lookups there than you need ... In this case, you could probably do something like:

```
self.attrs['class'] = 'someclass %s' % self.attrs.get('class','')
```

This will give you:

```
'someclass '
```

if the `'class'` key isn't already in your dict however (which is one space different than before).

Comment: I like one line solutions, but this space makes difference to me.

Comment: @StaticX -- You could always `.rstrip()` at the end of it all if you need to. `('someclass %s' % self.attrs.get('class','')).rstrip()` -- in Cpython, this is pretty efficient.  It doesn't create a new string unless it actually needs to.

Comment: add the other 2 solutions in Eric answer, I will mark yours as the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

@mgilson's answer is great. This is another approach that maybe is easier to understand and solves the last space problem:

```
if 'class' in self.attrs:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % self.attrs['class']
else:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass"
```

Answer (score 2):

Why rely on exceptions when you can just use membership testing:

```
# tests if class exists in the dictionary attrs
if 'class' in self.attrs:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % self.attrs['class']
else:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass"
```

or at the very least, remove the noop try:

```
# tests if class exists in the dictionary attrs
try:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % self.attrs['class']
except KeyError:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass"
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is inefficient because on the success path it still looks up the original `'class'` value twice.  Try this instead

```
try:
    v = self.attrs['class']
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % v
except KeyError:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass"
```

Comment: I agree, my mistake. I like your solution, but @diego-herranz doesn't need this auxiliary variable 'v' you created. Although using try is more pythonic. It is bad I can't select the two answers..

Comment: @StaticX no worries, you should always pick the answer you feel is best.

Answer (score 1):

The type of the exception won't change but there are two solutions that might be better:

1. You can use `attrs.get('class', 'someclass')`, i.e. provide a default value if the key can't be found
2. Extend `UserDict` and overwrite `__missing__()`:

   ```
   class ListDict(UserDict):
       def __missing__(key):
           return ['someclass']
   ```

That gives you a dictionary which automatically creates a new list for all missing keys. You can now use it like this:

```
self.attrs['class'].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the name of the exception shouldn't be changing, but in case you need to perform that kind of logic over a dictionary (to add a new element if it's not there or to update if it is), could be also implemented like the following (is an example, I hope it helps):

```
if not "class" in self.attrs:

   self.attrs['class'] = 'newclass'
else:
    self.attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % self.attrs['class']
```

The first part of the conditional checks if the element is within the list of keys of the dict. That should be useful for you as a sort of "idiom".
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the attrs dictionary yourself you could use a [DefaultDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

attrs = defaultdict(str)

attrs['class'] = "someclass %s" % attrs['class']
```